# Onclick=\"alert('hi');\" works, but onclick=\"function_name();\" does't work, ajax with javascript and php

Tags: php, ajax, onclick

I have two files:
inventory.php which has some javascript functions, one called (items) which looks like:

```
    function items(page,cat,order,column)
{
alert('hiiiiii');//testing msg

    var xhr = new getNewXmlHttpObj();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
    if(xhr.readyState == 4)
    {
    //alert(xhr.responseText);
    document.getElementById('items').innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
     }
    }
    var URL="ajax/inventory_items.php";
    xhr.open("POST",URL,true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    var info="page="+page+"&cat="+cat+"&order="+order+"&column="+column+"&dummy=" + new Date().getTime();
    xhr.send(info);
}
```

and the other file inventory_items.php which returns an HTML code to be displayed in the items div.
in inventory_items I have a link for the next page like this:

```
echo "<a href='#' class='red' onclick=\"items($next_page,$cat,$order,$column); return false; \">Next</a>";
```

the problem is with onclick, it doesn't call the (items) function at all, while changing to onclick=\"alert('something');\" works!

I am wondering whats the problem, I had this same code on windows (before win8) and it was working perfectly, but now I am using windows 8, does it make any difference?
how can I make the onclick work?
please help

Comment: I'd highly recommend a more descriptive title that describes the issue you are hitting.

Comment: did you include inventory.php file in inventory_items.php???

Comment: Do any errors show up in your console?

Comment: Darren- no errors. Noob- the output from inventory_items.php will display in inventory.php so I can't include inventory.php in inventory_items.php, it actually raise an error

Answer (score 0):

fixed it!
the problem is that I had to include the non-number variable in single quotation marks, as follows:

```
<a href='#' class='red' onclick=\"items($next_page,$cat,'$order','$column'); return false; \">Next</a>
```